# Why i m only getting the first word of the list

Tags: python

why I am getting only the first word of the list

```
def concat_short_words(s):
    i = 0
    word = s.split()
    while i < len(word):
        if len(word[i]) <= 4:
            result = "".join(word[i])

            return(result)
        i = i+1
```

Comment: `return` should be outside loop or you will end up returning from function in the first pass itself.

Comment: Why did you post the same function twice?

Comment: `"".join(word[i])` is the same as just `word[i]`.

Comment: You should create a list of all the short words, and after the loop is done return `"".join(smallwords)`

Comment: Don't use a `while` loop to iterate over a list. Use `for oneword in word:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignoring what I'm assuming is the accidental duplication of this function, you are returning the result of the first word matched. The return keyword will exit the function concat_short_words with the result as the returned value. Therefore, at the point of the first match to your predicate "len(word[i) <= 4" you will exit the function with the return value of the word matched. What you are probably trying to do is the following:

```
def concat_short_words(s):
    i = 0
    word = s.split()
    result = ""
    while i < len(word):
        if len(word[i]) <= 4:
            result = result + word[i]
        i = i+1

    return(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def concat_short_words(s):
  i=0
  result=[]
  word=s.split()
  while i<len(word):
     if len(word[i])<=4:
        result.append(word[i])
     i+=1
  return result
```

Answer (score 0):

the function ends with a single iteration due to "return" so you have to put it outside the loop

Answer (score 0):

You need a variable to hold your results and the correct indentation:

```
def concat_short_words(s):
    i = 0
    word = s.split()
    result = ""
    while i < len(word):
        if len(word[i]) <= 4:
            result += word[i]
        i = i+1
    return(result)

concat_short_words('The temperature is 22.625 ˚C')

'Theis˚C'
```

Your function can be rewritten more succinctly using a for loop:

```
def concat_short_words(s):
  result = ""
  for word in s.split():
      if len(word) <= 4:
          result += word
  return(result)

concat_short_words('The temperature is 22.625 ˚C')

'Theis˚C'
```

Comment: I am looking with while loop

Comment: I updated the answer to include a working function with a while loop.